# How to upload a CSV file on mysql server using php

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

The below code is suppose to upload CSV file to WAMP server , but it isnt

```
<?php
@$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("ddf",$con);

define('CSV_PATH','C:/Users/mshaikh/Desktop/Customs Compliance/CSV Files - 1000 Deposit/');
 $csv_file = CSV_PATH . $_POST['t1'];

if (($getfile = fopen($csv_file, "r")) !== FALSE) { 
        $data = fgetcsv($getfile, 1000, ",");
        while (($data = fgetcsv($getfile, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
         $num = count($data); 
         for ($c=0; $c < 1; $c++) {
             $result = $data; 
             $str = implode(",", $result); 
             $slice = explode(",", $str);
             $col1 = $slice[0]; 
             $col2 = $slice[1];
             $col3 = $slice[2];
             $col4 = $slice[3]; 
             $col5 = $slice[4];
             $col6 = $slice[5];  
             $col7 = $slice[6]; 
             $col8 = $slice[7];
             $col9 = $slice[8];
             $col10 = $slice[9]; 
             $col11 = $slice[10];
             $col12 = $slice[11];
             $col13 = $slice[12]; 
             $col14 = $slice[13];
             $col15 = $slice[14];
             $col16 = $slice[15]; 
             $col17 = $slice[16];
             $col18 = $slice[17];  
             $col19 = $slice[18]; 
             $col20 = $slice[19];
```

sql query to insert the csv to wamp

```
  $query = "INSERT INTO pl(DELIVERYNO,PACK_NAME,PALLETNO,CARTONNO,ORDERREF,COO,UN_ID,MATERIAL_CODE,MATERIAL_DESC,QTY,MFG_CODE,SAP_BATCH,NET_WEIGHT,GROSS_WEIGHT,TOTAL_UNIT_NETWEIGHT,DIM_CM,TARIFF_NO,MATERIAL_NO,EANUPC,SHIP_QTY)
    VALUES('".$col1."','".$col2."','".$col3."','".$col4."','".$col5."','".$col6."','".$col7."','".$col8."','".$col9."','".$col10."','".$col11."','".$col12."','".$col13."','".$col14."','".$col15."','".$col16."','".$col17."','".$col18."','".$col19."','".$col20."')";
    $s=mysql_query($query, $con ); 
         }
       } 
      }
    echo "File data successfully imported to database!!"; 
    mysql_close($con); 
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I wonder why don't you use [Load Data Infile](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) rather than looping over the file!
Here are [use cases for load data commands](http://kedar.nitty-witty.com/blog/load-delimited-data-csv-excel-into-mysql-server) as well.